# P-values for each comparison in a Kruskal post hoc test in R?

Tags: r, statistics, p-value, posthoc, kruskal-wallis

The `kruskalmc()` function from the pgirmess package does not output p values for each comparison, and I’m wondering whether there is a different function that performs a similar post hoc test after `kruskal.test()` that does output the p-values for each comparison.

If not, is there anyway to calculate the p-values from the data given in `kruskalmc()`?

Comment: If you have statistical questions about calculating p-values, you should probably ask for help instead at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.